# Looped Knower Paradox?

Tags: logic, paradox

Before I ask my question, let me elaborate on why I have the question. Consider two versions of the Looped Liar paradox.

3-Member Liar paradox:
L1: L2 is false
L2: L3 is false
L3: L1 is false

Jourdain's Paradox (Yes-No paradox):
L1: L2 is true
L2: L1 is false

I suspect that the 3-Member Liar paradox cannot be proven with the following two rules concerning the truth predicate:
T-Elim: T(⌜φ⌝) ⊢ φ
T-weak-Intro: If ⊢ φ then ⊢ T(⌜φ⌝)
But I know that Jourdain's paradox can be proven with these two rules only.

These rules have their analogs in the Knower paradox. T-Elim corresponds to the Factivity of Knowledge, and T-weak-Intro is the Principle of Necessitation (replace "T" with the "is known" predicate). So, I'm wondering if there is a similar thing going on with the Knower paradox.

Has anyone proven a version of the Knower paradox similar to the 3-member or Jourdain paradox?
The basic Knower paradox is:
K: K is not known

I want to know if my suspicion of the 3-Member Liar is correct.

Comment: If you admit both TE and TI in your 'paradoxical' HOL or set-theoretic like 1st order logic as primitive predicate's rules, indeed to prove 3-member Liar paradox above you need apparently one additional negation flip rule, namely, not T(⌜φ⌝) ⊢ T(⌜not φ⌝), then immediately you can rigorously prove the 3-Liar. As for the knower paradox with is-known primitive predicate in the same 'paradoxical' logic along with your mentioned 2 corresponding rules inspired modally, it'll be exactly same proof following the classic 1-liar paradox which is easier than yes-no paradox by replacing T with K...

Comment: Great! I also proved the Yes-No paradox with the is-known predicate. I did notice that we would need the axiom you mentioned to prove 3-member versions, and the axiom is provable with T-Intro. So I guess it makes sense that in the Knower paradox context, the 3-member version is not provable because the axiom would not hold for the is-known predicate.